# Facebook v2.0 Login with C# facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

It looks like C# facebook SDK (https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) still uses Login v1.0:

FacebookClient.OAuthResult.cs:

```
public partial class FacebookClient
{
    ...
    public virtual Uri GetDialogUrl(string dialog, object parameters)
    {
        ...
        sb.AppendFormat(isMobile ? "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/{0}?" : "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/{0}?", dialog);
    }
}
```

My question is:
Will it be updated to https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?

Thanks,
Yury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an active branch at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/tree/graph-api-v2 that has been working on getting it to allow version based access to the API.

Try using that branch or subscribe to the open issue for [Support for Graph 2.0](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/294).